# SharpZipLib : Compressing a single file to a single compressed file

Tags: c#, compression, sharpziplib

I am currently working with SharpZipLib under .NET 2.0 and via this I need to compress a single file to a single compressed archive.  In order to do this I am currently using the following:

```
string tempFilePath = @"C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9AE0.tmp.xml";
string archiveFilePath = @"C:\Archive\Archive_[UTC TIMESTAMP].zip";

FileInfo inFileInfo = new FileInfo(tempFilePath);
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip fZip = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.FastZip();
fZip.CreateZip(archiveFilePath, inFileInfo.Directory.FullName, false, inFileInfo.Name);
```

This works exactly (ish) as it should, however while testing I have encountered a minor gotcha.  Lets say that my temp directory (i.e. the directory that contains the uncompressed input file) contains the following files:

```
tmp9AE0.tmp.xml //The input file I want to compress
xxx_tmp9AE0.tmp.xml // Some other file
yyy_tmp9AE0.tmp.xml // Some other file
wibble.dat // Some other file
```

When I run the compression all the `.xml` files are included in the compressed archive.  The reason for this is because of the final `fileFilter` parameter passed to the `CreateZip` method.  Under the hood SharpZipLib is performing a pattern match and this also picks up the files prefixed with `xxx_` and `yyy_`.  I assume it would also pick up anything postfixed as well.

So the question is, how can I compress a single file with SharpZipLib?  Then again maybe the question is how can I format that `fileFilter` so that the match can only ever pick up the file I want to compress and nothing else.

As an aside, is there any reason as to why `System.IO.Compression` not include a `ZipStream` class? (It only supports GZipStream)

EDIT : Solution (Derived from accepted answer from Hans Passant)

This is the compression method I implemented:

```
private static void CompressFile(string inputPath, string outputPath)
{
    FileInfo outFileInfo = new FileInfo(outputPath);
    FileInfo inFileInfo = new FileInfo(inputPath);

    // Create the output directory if it does not exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(outFileInfo.Directory.FullName))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(outFileInfo.Directory.FullName);
    }

    // Compress
    using (FileStream fsOut = File.Create(outputPath))
    {
        using (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream(fsOut))
        {
            zipStream.SetLevel(3);

            ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry newEntry = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry(inFileInfo.Name);
            newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            using (FileStream streamReader = File.OpenRead(inputPath))
            {
                ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core.StreamUtils.Copy(streamReader, zipStream, buffer);
            }

            zipStream.CloseEntry();
            zipStream.IsStreamOwner = true;
            zipStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As to your aside: ZipStream wouldn't make much sense, since ZIP is an archive format that can hold more than one file. I suppose they could have provided a full API for reading and writing and ZIPs, but that would obviously have been much more effort than GZipStream.

Comment: As an aside of my own, as you're only compressing a single file, is there a reason why you don't want to just use GZip compression, which, as you note, has support within the framework?

Comment: I would love to, I could do this with a couple of lines of code.  It has to be zip as our 'support' desk can't handle the complexities of gzip (did that sound sarcastic?? ;))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an XY problem, just don't use FastZip.  Follow the first example on [this web page](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/SharpZipLib-Zip-Samples.ashx) to avoid accidents.

Comment: That works, however the compressed archive includes all the directories as well.  It would be better if the archive just contain the file at the root level and nothing else.

Comment: string entryName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename);